# Bash programming, reading in a value and a file name

Tags: bash

Okay, here is what I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash 

read num 

while read line
do 
    name=$line 
    echo "Text from file: $name" 
    for i in {0..num}; do 
        echo -e "\n" 
    done 
done <$1
```

The idea is simply to read in a file and put spaces between each line. The user inputs the number of spaces they would like to add between each line (read in with "num"). The objective is to be able to type in the console: 
./fileName 3 readFile

And it should output the text from the readFile with 3 spaces between each line. Instead it gives me an error that says "line 13: 3: No such file or directory". So it is not reading 3 in as an integer, it's trying to open a file called "3". How do I make it stop this? If you have a better solution, your input is appreciated. I'm a bit new to bash so I'm sorry for noob status. Any help is appreciated, thank you community.

Comment: You can't include variables in `{}` expansion, use `$(seq 0 $num)`. Also you probably want to start the expansion at 1, otherwise 1 space, equals two iterations `0` and `1`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that, but it is still giving me the error "No such file or directory". Am I doing my inputs correctly?

Comment: Does your file contain spaces in the filename? `$1` should be quoted to prevent word splitting on the right sight of the redirection.

Comment: `for i in {1..${num}} ; do echo $i ; done` works in ksh, not certain about bash. Good luck to all.

Comment: Also you should have `while IFS= read -r line`, if you want to avoid '\' special character processing and trimming preceding and trailing whitespace.

Comment: No spaces in the filename, but that does help eliminate another error I was having. Everything works fine if I stop trying to read in "num". So am I doing that correctly? For some reason when I put in ./fileName 3 readFile it is trying to search for a file named "3".

Comment: `read num` takes input from stdin and assigns it to variable num on the return character. If you do `./fileName 3 readFile`, 3 is argument `$1`, readfile is argument `$2`. So just changing it to `num=$1` should fix the issue. Still need to change the brace expansion and I would change the while loop and quote `"$1"` at the end, to avoid future errors.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
nSpaceFile() {
    # Create the sed script we need to space the file out.
    # One `G;` for each extra line we want to add.
    declare sedscript=$(printf -- %*s $(($1 - 1)) | sed -e 's/ /G;/g');

    # Run the sed script on the file(s) given. 
    sed "$sedscript" "${@:2}"
}

nSpaceFile 3 file
```

Explanation of the sed command (and many other sed one-liners) available [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt).

Answer (score 0):

To quote `man bash`:

```
To  avoid  conflicts  with  parameter expansion, the string ${ is not
considered eligible for brace expansion.
```

So variables can't be expanded inside brace expansion.  For these situations I use `seq`.  You could alternatively use `eval` but that's not recommended if it can be avoided as it can open you up to code injection.

As @BroSlow mentioned, when invoking like `./fileName 3 readFile`, `3` is argument `$1` and `readFile` is argument `$2`.

You could write your script like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line ]]; then
        echo "$line"
        for i in $(seq $1); do
            echo
        done
    fi
done < "$2"
```

But it would be more efficient to use `awk` over a `read` loop, especially for large files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

NF {
    print
    for(i=1; i<=num;i++)
        printf "\n"
}
```

Make the script executable, and you can invoke it like this:

```
$ ./fileName.awk num=3 readFile
```